# Unable to get output from child process

Tags: javascript, node.js, macos, process, spawn

So, I have a simple app (I have written) which writes to `stdout`.

When I run it by itself, the output is being printed fine.

Now, when I spawn the process with node... nothing happens (apart from a message saying the process has finished)

**Here's my code:**

```
var spawn = require('child_process').spawn;
helper = spawn("myApp", []);
helper.stdout.on('data', function(data) { 
    console.log("GOT: " + data);
});
helper.stdout.on('end', function(data) {
    console.log("FINISHED: " + data);
});
helper.on('exit', function(code) {
    console.log("CLOSED!");
});
```

**And here's the output:**

```
FINISHED: undefined
CLOSED!
```

Yep, just that.

What's going on? Am I missing something?

Comment: The "end" event won't give you any content.

Comment: When I change the `spawn()` to `spawn("sh", ["-c", "echo hello world"])` it works fine for me, though I get the "close" event before the data.

Comment: Well, the `end` even *does* fire. The `stdout.on('data',...)` part isn't...

Comment: Are you sure that your application code properly flushes its output buffers? (Not super-likely to be the case, but the child process stuff is pretty darned close to a raw wrapper around the underlying system calls.)

Comment: Hmm... Am I? That's a good question. It's an Objective-C terminal app, `fprintf`ing to `stdout`... Let me double-check.

Comment: @Pointy Wow.... Well, I just made the `myApp` app `fprint` to `stderr` and then attach the event handlers there. And... it worked!!! Thanks a lot for pointing me to the right direction. Just post it as an answer and I'll accept it. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure your stdio output buffers are being flushed in your application:

```
  fflush(stdout); // or something like that
```

Output straight to the tty has less buffering than output to a pipe.

Comment: @Dr.Kameleon no problem - fun opportunity to use some stuff I had forgotten I even knew :)

Comment: The trouble is that I had forgotten too. I guess there are times like this when it all comes back up... haha.